# delete on trigger on multiple views

Tags: oracle

How do I use a trigger to delete from multiple tables ?
"name" (of the country) is a foreign key in tables fronteer, locate, cross

I wrote this, it compiles but when I tried to execute the procedure associated "deletecountry", it says

```
01732. 00000 -  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"
```

Here is the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_d_country
    INSTEAD OF DELETE ON country
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        delete from fronteer where namep=:OLD.name or namef=:OLD.name;
        delete from locate where namep=:OLD.name;
        delete from cross where name=:OLD.name;
        delete from country where name=:OLD.name;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the views has operators like `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, etc. or explicitly created with `WITH READ ONLY` clause.

Have a look at CONSTRAINT with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, it may solve your requirements much simpler (otherwise review your data design):

```
ALTER TABLE locate ADD (
  CONSTRAINT locate_country_FK 
  FOREIGN KEY (NAME) 
  REFERENCES country (NAME)
  ON DELETE CASCADE);
```